# Android: Why does long click also trigger a normal click?

Tags: android, events, listview, onlongclicklistener

I have a ListView with listeners for a long click and a regular click.

Why, when I long press a list item, the regular click event gets called too?

I need to have two separate functions for the different clicks.

Answer (score 305, accepted):

From [Event Listeners](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html#EventListeners):

> [onLongClick()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html#onLongClick%28android.view.View%29) - This returns a boolean to indicate whether you have consumed the event and it should not be carried further. That is, return true to indicate that you have handled the event and it should stop here; return false if you have not handled it and/or the event should continue to any other on-click listeners.

Are you returning `true` from your `onLongClick()` and still getting the normal click event?

**Edited to add**: For a ListView, you may be using `OnItemLongClickListener`.  The [`onItemLongClick()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener.html#onItemLongClick%28android.widget.AdapterView%3C?%3E,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29) there uses a similar boolean return value to indicate whether it consumed the event.

Comment: For setting the `myListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(this); ` option, you'll have to Override the function `public boolean onItemLongClick(...)`.  Here you simply need to `return true` which indicates that the LongClick was activated and will cancel the trigger on the regular click.  If you return false then it'll trigger the regular click as well.

Comment: what about the other situation, when i need to differ between the long click and normal click to take action according to that

Comment: @erichamion I tried your solution for a similar issue, with no luck.  I'd appreciate any insights or thoughts you could provide, located here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47783631/recyclerview-how-to-add-onclick-and-keep-onlongclick-working

Answer (score 61):

Restating the answer in simpler terms:

Given:

```
@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

    return true; // or false
}
```

- `return true` means that the event is consumed. It is handled. No other click events will be notified.
- `return false` means the event is not consumed. Any other click events will continue to receive notifications.

So if you don't want `onClick` to also be triggered after an `onLongClick`, then you should `return true` from the `onLongClick` event.

Comment: Super perfect answer if we put true value then it only handle long click if we put false then both click and long press event occur at once

Answer (score 20):

Make sure you are overriding `OnClickListener` for your `onClick` method. Also make sure you are overriding `OnLongClickListener` for your `onLongClick` method. And make sure that your `onLongClick` method returns `true`, as this will consume the `onClick`.

Comment: I added true in my onLongClick method but still have an issue in that my onClick method doesn't fire thereafter.  I would appreciate any thoughts or ideas on how to solve, located here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47783631/recyclerview-how-to-add-onclick-and-keep-onlongclick-working

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `setOnLongClickListener` creating an instance of `new View.OnClickListener()` or `new View.OnLongClickListener()`, if you create a Long click and implements a normal OnclickListener you will get this errors of single click activating the method.
You should use `new View.OnLongClickListener()` for catching only long clicks